# Unable to publish message from KafkaProducer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am unable to send message from Kafka Producer. My configuration is not working and it looks like this:

```java
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "127.0.0.1:9092");
properties.setProperty("key.serializer", StringSerializer.class.getName());
properties.setProperty("value.serializer", StringSerializer.class.getName());
properties.setProperty("acks", "1");
properties.setProperty("retries", "3");
properties.setProperty("linger.ms", "1");

Producer<String, String> producer =
    new org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer<String, String>(properties);
ProducerRecord<String, String> producerRecord =
    new ProducerRecord<String, String>("second_topic", "3", "messagtest");
Future<RecordMetadata> s = producer.send(producerRecord);

producer.flush();
producer.close();
```

Here is error after i did s.get();

```
 java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for second_topic-0: 30021 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.FutureRecordMetadata.valueOrError(FutureRecordMetadata.java:94)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.FutureRecordMetadata.get(FutureRecordMetadata.java:64)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.FutureRecordMetadata.get(FutureRecordMetadata.java:29)
at ai.sys.producer.Test.main(Test.java:33)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for second_topic-0: 30021 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time
```

Comment: What happens? Are there any errors?

Comment: Try running `s.get()` before closing the producer or send more than one message

Comment: @MickaelMaison no any errors.

Comment: @MickaelMaison  here is error i got.

Comment: @cricket_007 i got this after you instruction

Comment: can you verify your kafka server is running on `127.0.0.1:9092` through the console

Comment: @Deadpool  no doubt yes it is running.  i tried from terminal it is working xD

Comment: can you try this by removing this property `properties.setProperty("linger.ms", "1");` and having this property `properties.setProperty("batch.size", "0");`

Answer (score 1):

Batching has been enabled in Kafka Producer by default with a size of 16K Bytes. However, in your code, you are sending only one record which might not satisfy the batch size.

Hence, for your code to work, try to add the following property of "batch.size" to value "0" to Kafka Producer properties.

```
properties.setProperty("batch.size", "0");
```

This would disable the batching mechanism and allow your producer to write records to the Kafka Broker.

**Note:** In real-time, disabling batching would increase the number of write requests to the broker and decrease the I/O Throughput and performance of both the producer and server.